# "От добра добра не ищут" — смысл пословицы

Tags: фразеология

Меня всегда озадачивала пословица (или это все-таки поговорка?) "от добра добра не ищут". О каком добре тут идет речь? О добре как моральной категории или добре в смысле материальных благ?

Comment: По-моему, "в смысле материальных благ" правильней, чем "в смысле материальные блага".

Comment: @М_Г ну а что ж не исправили-то? :)

Comment: @Aer Система не принимает исправлениe, если исправлено менее  х символов (кажется, х=6)

Comment: @М_Г точно! Тогда через связь с модератором лучше предлагать (через тревогу), в комментах могу не увидеть. Ну а с ростом репутации вы и сами сможете избегать этих ограничений на правку)

Answer (score 6):

Мне попадалось это выражение в 2 значениях:

1. Лучшее - враг хорошего, и не стоит искать добра, если оно у тебя уже есть. "От овса кони не рыщут, а от добра добра не ищут."
2. Не стоит ждать ответной реакции, если сделал кому-то доброе дело. Слышал в повседневной речи, если кто-то отвечал злом на добро.

Answer (score 6):

У Ушакова читаем про одно из значений предлога "от":

> > Употр. в знач.: при **наличии** кого-чего-н., несмотря на наличие кого-чего-н. «Какой-то греховодник женился от живой жены еще на двух.» Крылов. «От добра добра не ищут.» Пословица. От силы (см. сила).

То есть если у тебя всё хорошо ("есть" добро), то стремиться к ещё лучшему не всегда стоит.

Answer (score 4):

Еще можно на эту тему дать такое толкование:

**от овса кони не рыщут** - если это действительно овес, то кони от него не отвернутся, а признают в нем овес и будут есть и не будут при этом рыскать в поиске овса, т.к. он уже перед ними;

**от добра добра не ищут** - если то, что свершается, действительно добро , и ты это признаешь, то не следует искать другого добра, потому что другое добро - это НЕ добро (НЕ добро = зло).
(При условии, что ты реально можешь отличить добро от зла и видеть, где добро, а где зло в овечьей шкуре.)

И еще, тут говорится о том, что не нужно смотреть на то, ***какое*** это добро: "Он делает мне добро, но бывает добро еще добрее.. Пойду поищу..."
*Кони так не рассуждают, для них овес - это овес.*

Answer (score 3):

Мои мысли в ответ на поставленные вопросы.

**Вопрос**: Пословица или поговорка?

**Ответ**: По-моему, это пословица.  @Людмила тоже так считает. А Викисловарь указывает, что это поговорка. Может быть, причина в том, что это только часть пословицы «От овса кони не рыщут, а от добра добра не ищут», а часть пословицы, согласно Далю, может стать поговоркой («складная короткая речь, ходячая в народе, но не составляющая полной пословицы»). И вот еще одно мнение: "Пословица не указывает, что делать или не делать, а просто констатирует житейскую ситуацию." (@bernard)

**Вопрос**: О каком добре тут идет речь? О добре как моральной категории или добре в смысле материальных благ?

**Ответ**: По-моему, не совсем верно составлено противопоставление «добро как  моральная категория  - материальные блага». Нематериальные блага тоже не относятся к моральной категории добра. Добро как моральная категория есть намеренное, бескорыстное и искреннее стремление к осуществлению блага, полезного деяния. С некоторой натяжкой можно сказать, что это понятие охватывает также добрые дела, но никак не моральные блага.

Но вернемся к нашей поговорке. Как оказалось, у нее есть как минимум два значения:

1. *Довольствуйся тем хорошим, что есть, и не ищи лучшего; говорится тогда, когда не хотят менять существующего положения, порядка, образа жизни и т. п.*

В этом значении «добро» близко по смыслу к «хорошо», поэтому охватывает как материальные, так и нематериальные условия, но это не относится к моральной категории добра

2. *Не жди добра в ответ на добро.*

Здесь можно понимать добро и в смысле каких-то благ (материальных и нет), и в смысле добрых дел, и в смысле моральной категории добра (например, можно понимать эту поговорку так, что добрые дела не увеличивают количества добра в этом мире)

Answer (score 2):

Это поговорка. Означает, что, когда всё хорошо и складно, не надо пытаться сделать лучше - добрые побуждения могут привести к плохим последствиям, и потеряешь то хорошее, что имеешь сейчас.

Comment: Почему ж поговорка, если это целое предложение - обобщённо-личное в форме неопределённо-личного? Поговорки самостоятельно не употребляются, это пословица, вернее половина её, у Владислава - полный вариант. "От овса(или от корма)кони не рыщут, а от добра добра не ищут"

Comment: Первая  половина  и  есть  объяснение  для  второй.  Пословица  не  указывает,  что  делать  или  не  делать,  а  просто  констатирует  житейскую  ситуацию.  Хотя,  некое  назидание  усмотреть  вполне  возможно.

Answer (score 2):

Надо быть благодарным за все, что у тебя есть хорошее. Если ты вечно чем-то недоволен, ты всегда будешь искать что-то другое, что может привести тебя к разбитому корыту (так, например, как в сказке Пушкина - у старухи было все, о чем можно было мечтать, но нет... ей надо было всегда больше...вот и осталась у разбитого корыта. Потеряла все.) Вот и говорят : " От добра добра не ищут".

Comment: О добре как моральной категории или добре в смысле материальные блага? Таков вопрос.

Comment: @shampar я не профессионал в этом, но обобщая весь свой опыт, когда я слышала эту пословицу, здесь имеется в виду все хорошее, что у Вас есть в жизни - любовь, забота, помощь, дом, пища насущная - т.е. все, за что можно быть благодарным. Если быть недовольным, что есть, то потеряешь и это! Конечно, это нередкость, когда человек не чувствует, что у него очень много в жизни хорошего.

Comment: Не хотел развивать тему «на полях». Я просто процитировал суть вопроса, который пока ещё не имеет ответа: о каком добре речь?

Answer (score 2):

Если хочешь сделать добро (добрый поступок), не жди отдачи — делай от души.

Answer (score 1):

Эта поговорка значит, что если кони сыты, то другого овса себе не рыщут. И если человек любит одного человека (со всеми вытекающими последствиями),то другого человека для любви не ищет. Другими словами, обратная поговорке "Сколько волка не корми он все в лес смотрит".

Comment: очень интересная версия

Answer (score 1):

**Смысл таков:** делая добро другим, не жди добра взамен, не жди, что другие тебе ответят тем же (добром).

Answer (score 1):

Друзья! Скорее всего, я не права.... Но все же, внесу свои "три копейки"!

Рысак - конь, способный к веселому бегу(рысью). "От овса": овес - сытная для коня еда! Если лошадь кормить одним овсом, у неё начинает болеть живот. Т.е. *от овса* (переедания) *конь становится вялым, ленивым.* Таким образом, ***от овса конь не рыщет!***

Если в первой и второй части пословицы проводить смысловую аналогию, то получается, что *сытый*(богатый) *человек не пойдёт искать добро,* у него и так все в порядке, *ему лениво.* Короче, нас и здесь неплохо кормят, зачем нам на Таити?

Стало быть, **"добро"** в данной пословице, в первой части - ***некие материальные блага, которые затрудняют человеку получение "добра", как счастья!***
Значит, *пословица о том, чтобы не набивать мошну, а стремиться к духовности!*
О как загнула!
Но на истину в последней инстанции не претендую, просто фантазирую...

Comment: А разве кто-то возражает, что "добро" в первой, да и второй части, материальные блага?

Answer (score 1):

Хм...  А как вам такой вариант?  Добро есть бескорыстное деяние — в этом его суть. Ибо, если ты получил или ожидаешь оплату за свой поступок, то это уже не доброе дело, а платная услуга. Таким образом, тут говорится следующее: если твой поступок есть добро, то не ищи от него выгоды и не ожидай в ответ зеркального к тебе отношения. Иначе любое добро перестает быть добром.
А первая часть поговорки — "от овса конь не рыщет" — указывает на отношение, с которым нужно подходить к добрым делам: не бегать от них, как не бегает от овса лошадь. Потому что добрые дела для человека есть его пища.
Так говорил Христос своим ученикам о людях, собравшихся послушать его: "Есть у меня пища, о которой вы не знаете. Эта пища есть воля Божия". Так и добрые дела являются такой же волей Божией.

Answer (score 0):

Люди добрые, это пословица!
Пословица — это целое предложение со смыслом, а поговорка — лишь красивая фраза или словосочетание. Это главный признак, отличающий пословицы от поговорок.

Пословица содержит нравоучение, примету, предостережение или наставление. Поговорка — просто красноречивое выражение, которое можно легко заменить другими словами.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Пословицы:
*Мал золотник, да дорог.

Пустая бочка громче гремит.

Не зная броду, не суйся в воду.*

Поговорки: *«мал, да удал», «как собака на сене», «остаться с носом»*.

Comment: Про пословицу вообще — понятно, так ведь речь о конкретной.

Answer (score 0):

Забавно, чаще всего встречал и использовал выражение в ключе указания на причину действия:
В пословице:
От добра добра не ищут, кони от овса не рыщут (был бы овес в яслях не рыскали бы, значит солому заложили).
В диалогах:

-- Петька по девкам от жены бегает.

-- От добра добра не ищут ( жена плохая ).

=====

-- Иван больничный взял и по собеседованиям ходит.

-- От добра добра не ищут ( не устраивает текущая работа )

=====

Comment: Во-первых, что тут забавного? А во-вторых, ответ сформулируете пожалуйста. В таком виде это максимум комментарий.